# Use nested query value inside case when without reusing function within nested query

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

In SQL Server, I am trying to create a select query that calls a function to get a column value. But I also want to use that value to do a case when to choose a value based on the condition.

It's theoretically possible to get this value before my SQL statement into a variable, but I am trying to avoid this since I need to do this for about 30+ columns resulting in that many variables to be used.

The function I am using will return either a single scalar value or NULL, it does a couple of select queries.

What I am trying to achieve

```
SELECT
    mainCol1, maincol2,
    CASE 
        WHEN (myFunction(@param1, @param2)) IS NULL 
            THEN myFunction(@param1, @param2)
            ELSE maincol3
    END,
    -- ...
```

... and so on.

I tried calling the function twice, both within the `case when` and tried storing value from function into a variable (this results in errors).

```
SELECT 
    mainCol1, maincol2,
    CASE 
        WHEN (SELECT (myFunction(@param1, @param2)) IS NULL 
            THEN myFunction(@param1, @param2) AS col3 val) 
            THEN col3Val 
            ELSE maincol3
    END,
    -- ...
```

Comment: You can do a subselect.  Put your select inside another select and use the function returned value from the subselect.

Comment: Can you include a little more of your code? Are you actually passing _variables_ into the function rather than _columns_? If you are, you can just call `myFunction` once outside your select statement, and substitute its value there. It sort of sounds like you said you tried that, but it seems like it should work if you're passing variables to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so first things first, if you really just need to check if the function result is NULL, and then do something else, you can obviate this whole discussion and just do `isnull(MyFunction(<my inputs>), Col3)`. **Full stop, you're done**. You've only had to call `MyFunction` once for that column.

But let's take it a bit further and assume the thing you want to check is more complicated than just "if the first argument null, give me the second argument" and explore some other options.

**SETUP**

```
-- Create a function which can return null
create or alter function dbo.MyFunction
(
    @Param1 int,
    @Param2 int
)
returns float as
begin

return (1 * 1.0) / nullif(@Param2, 0)
end
go

-- Populate some data.
drop table if exists #MyTable
create table #MyTable
(
    Col1 int,
    Col2 int,
    Col3 int
)

insert into #MyTable
values
    (5, 0, 10),
    (3, 1, 10),
    (1, -10, -5)
```

**Using variables as function parameters**

So as I mentioned above, the simple answer is to use `isnull`; a function which returns its second argument if the first is null. That alone makes calling the function only take place once. Assuming you are actually passing *variables* to the function, you can just do this:

```
declare @Param1 int = 5, @Param2 int = 0

declare @ScalarResult float = dbo.MyFunction(@Param1, @Param2)

SELECT 
    Col1,
    Col2,
    Col3 = isnull(@ScalarResult, Col3)
from #MyTable
```

However let's say you want to do a check that is more complicated that `isnull` can handle; let's say you want to return a different value if the function returns, say, a negative number.

It seems like the answer is: Call your function ahead of time, store it off in a variable, and just replace your function calls in the select statement with a reference to that variable.

I know you said you don't want to have a bunch of variables, but variables are cheap. Yes, it's a bit lengthy, but we're trying to optimize away the cost of calling a function multiple times. That's one of the best ways to do that.

```
-- Different ternary condition, checking for negative numbers
select @ScalarResult = dbo.MyFunction(1, -10)

select 
    Col1,
    Col2,
    Col3 = iif(@ScalarResult < 0, Col3, @ScalarResult)
from #MyTable
```

**If you need to do a function call against *columns* (or you don't like variables)**

Now if you want to do a function call whose inputs are columns (or you just find the notion of declaring 30+ variables anathema) then you can call your function in a `cross apply` and reuse that. I'll use the more complicated "if negative then something" logic because again, if it's just checking for nullability, the answer is: use `isnull` and you don't have a problem of calling the function more than once.

```
-- using columns as inputs
select 
    Col1,
    Col2,
    Col3 = iif(ScalarResult < 0, Col3, ScalarResult),
    Col4 = iif(ColumnResult < 0, Col3, ColumnResult)
from #MyTable
cross apply
(
    select 
        ColumnResult = dbo.MyFunction(Col1, Col2),
        ScalarResults =dbo.MyFunction(@Param1, @Param2)

) f
```

Here's the full [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vwkRQvtn) of my code.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to go fwd with the create 30 odd variables approach though... since my params are dependent on the field name and type as well... In any case no need to complicate it further...